# Unable to connect Serviceable Agent (sun.jvm.hotspot.HSDB) to running jvm on windows 7 (32 Bit)

Tags: java, linux, windows, ubuntu, jvm

As per the [link](http://www.oraclejavamagazine-digital.com/javamagazine/20120708?pg=42#pg42) I successfully be able to connect HSDB to running jvm process on Ubuntu by following steps below:

1. (On Ubuntu Terminal) `set SA_JAVA=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java`
2. (On Ubuntu Terminal) `echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope`
3. (On Ubuntu Terminal) `java -Dsun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.useProcDebugger=true -classpath /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-orcale/lib/sa-jdi.jar sun.jvm.hotspot.HSDB`

For Windows 7 32 Bit and from the same [link](http://www.oraclejavamagazine-digital.com/javamagazine/20120708?pg=42#pg42) I tried to connect sun.jvm.hotspot.HSDB with running jvm process but I am facing following problems:

1. (On command prompt) `set PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin;d:\windbg;%PATH%` . But in the above command I am not being able to find `d:\windbg`. For this dependency I Google a lot and also installed Microsoft Windows Debugger but after installation it has different folder hierarchy (`c:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1`).
2. For a while I skipped `"windbg"` and execute the following command.
   [image: Command]
   Which gives the following Screen.
   [image: Java Process ID Screen]
   On the above screen I entered running jvm `process id` which I gathered from Windows Task Manager and clicked on OK button.
   The following screen appears and caused an exception.
   [image: Processing]
   [image]
   I know the link I followed is very old. How can I run `sun.jvm.hotspot.HSDB` on windows. Or is there any other tool that I should follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that you are using `java.exe` from your **jre** insteand of your **jdk** to start hdsb. That's why it's looking for `sawindbg.dll` in your `jre\bin` (where it isn't found) instead of your `jdk\bin` (where the dll is). You can see that in the LinkError error message.

So use:

`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin\java.exe -cp C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\lib\sa-jdi.jar sun.jvm.hotspot.HSDB`

Or better change your path to always use the `java.exe` in your jdk. Other tools also have problem with the jre one as well.